# Django exclude on multiple fields in subquery

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Given some code like this:

```
# coding: utf-8
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site


class Premium(models.Model):
    """Access to Premium Features™®."""
    end = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)


def get_ending_premiums():
    """Get a queryset of all Premiums for which a user has none following."""
    tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    future_premiums = Premium.objects.filter(end__gt=tomorrow).values('user', 'site')
    return Premium.objects.filter(end=tomorrow).exclude(

        # Would love if something like this actually worked...
        user_and_site__in=future_premiums,
    )
```

How can I complete `get_ending_premiums()`? One of the key things is I want Premiums only when there isn't another one that ends later, **but** on a per-site basis. So if a user has another Premium on groceries.com, the one about to end tomorrow doesn't get returned, but if they don't have another Premium on officesupplies.com, that one *does* get returned.

(Note the line with with the comments before it doesn’t actually work... that’s the part I need to complete.)

I can work out how to do this outside the ORM but I’d really prefer an ORM solution, as we’re planning on switching database vendors in a few months, so I’m trying to avoid raw SQL as much as possible.

Here’s a test for the behavior I’d like to get:

```
class PremiumTest(TestCase):

    def test_gets_ending_premiums(self):
        today = date(2020, 6, 5)
        tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
        next_year = today + timedelta(days=366)
        groceries = Site.objects.create(domain='groceries.com')
        catvids = Site.objects.create(domain='catvids.com')
        dave = User.objects.create_user('dave')
        sally = User.objects.create_user('sally')
        Premium.objects.create(user=dave, site=groceries, end=tomorrow)
        Premium.objects.create(user=dave, site=groceries, end=next_year)
        Premium.objects.create(user=dave, site=catvids, end=tomorrow)
        Premium.objects.create(user=sally, site=groceries, end=tomorrow)
        Premium.objects.create(user=sally, site=catvids, end=tomorrow)
        Premium.objects.create(user=sally, site=catvids, end=next_year)

        ending_premiums = get_ending_premiums(today)
        ending = set((p.user, p.site) for p in ending_premiums)

        self.assertNotIn((dave, groceries), ending)
        self.assertIn((dave, catvids), ending)
        self.assertIn((sally, groceries), ending)
        self.assertNotIn((sally, catvids), ending)
        self.assertEqual(2, len(ending_premiums))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this... It's got some raw SQL but it still returns a QuerySet with normal QuerySet methods (although it uses the apparently deprecated `QuerySet.extra()` method)

```
def get_ending_premiums(day=None):
    """Get a queryset of Premiums for which a user has none following."""
    if day is None:
        day = date.today()
    tomorrow = day + timedelta(days=1)

    ending_premiums = Premium.objects.filter(
        end=tomorrow,
    ).extra(
        where=['NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM premium_premium child where premium_premium.site_id = site_id AND premium_premium.user_id = user_id AND end > %s )'],
        params=[tomorrow],
    )
    return ending_premiums
```

Still wondering if there isn’t a better way...